# How do I import files into a scoped style tag without it bleeding out?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

I'm importing a css file in a style tag using a `.vue` file. The scoped css file is affecting all the css on my page and I only want it to affect my current component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
    @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
</style>
```

How do I import a css file that is scoped to my current component?

Comment: Insert scoped style into top level of your current component. https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: @bigless raw css scoped was deprecated around 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use sass?

First you'd have to install sass-loader:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .container {
       @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt seem to work. I'm using Laravel mix to handle my webpack.config file if that gives you any clues

Comment: You shouldn't really have to change anything in your config.

Comment: I cant get this to work. Without digging into it too much I think the sass loader doesn't support importing within a class.

Comment: I did a raw build just using scss and no vue to see what was going on. It rips out .container{} and just has the @import. Very weird.